# What is the dimension of this function? (And mostly: what does this mean?)

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, operator-theory

I'm really not understanding what this exercise is asking me:

> Find the dimension of $$f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2 \qquad \qquad f(\mathbb{R}^3) \subseteq \text{span} (0, 1)$$

Can someone please explain me what this means?

This is what I understood: $f$ is something like $f(x, y, z)$.
The arrival set is $\mathbb{R}^2$ so we have something (to say) like

$$f(x, y, z) = (xy + z, x^y - z^2)$$

(just a random example).

But then I don't know what $f(\mathbb{R}^3)$ means. It's a subset of span $(0,1)$ which are the infinite combinations of the vector $(0,1)$. Are they infinite? Or finite? And what is $f(\mathbb{R}^3)$?

I'm confused.

Comment: Minor remark: The word "operator" in linear algebra is used to refer to a linear map from a vector space to itself. The function in your question is not an "operator".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a function $f : A\to B$, the notation $$f(A)=\{b : \exists a\in A, f(a)=b\}$$

In other words, $f(A)$ is the range of the function $f$(the word range should not be used when talking about a subset of $A$, but when talking about $A$, the word range is appropriate).

You are given that $f(R^3)$ is a subset of the span of the vector $(0, 1)$. Meaning that the range of the function $f$ is a subset of $$\text{span}(0, 1)=\{a(0, 1) : a\in R\}$$

and are asked to find the dimension of range of $f$.

Recall that the dimension of a vector space is the length of the basis of that vector space. For the vector space $R^2$, the basis of this vector space is $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ as every vector $(x, y)\in R^2$ can be written as $(x, y)=x(1, 0)+y(0, 1)$. So, the dimension of $R^2$ is $2$.

Comment: Thank you. For every real $a$ (non zero) I have a different vector. So is this span an infinite set of vectors? In this sense, a subset of that span is a smaller set of vectors? How to count the dimension with no other information?

Comment: @Numb3rs I have added that to my answer. You should know the definition of dimension. And, yes. The span is an infinite set. But the set being infinite has no bearing on the dimension of the vector space.

Comment: Ah yes, I know what dimension menas. I just got confused because that span is just of one vector. But $(0, 1)$ is not sufficient to span $\mathbb{R}^2$, isn't it? I would have said the dimension is $2$, but that span $(0,1)$ hit me hard.

Comment: @Numb3rs Can you find a vector in span$(0, 1)$ such that every vector in span$(0, 1)$ can be written as a scalar multiple of that vector?

Comment: For example: $(0, n)$ is just $n (0, 1)$?

Comment: @Numb3rs Exactly! Now that you have a basis, what is the dimension of span$(0, 1)$?

Comment: I would dare to say it's $1$ then, since one vector is sufficient...

Comment: @Numb3rs That is correct. Now recall that the dimension can only ever be a non-negative integer. So, what are possible dimensions of the subspaces of span$(0, 1)$?

Comment: Well then since every set is itself's own subset too, I would again dare to say it's one. Or zero (can it be?)

Comment: @Numb3rs That is correct! The only possible dimension of a subspace of span$(0, 1)$ are $0$ or $1$. Since the range of a function is a subspace, what are the possible dimensions of $f(A)$?

Comment: Then it must be either one or zero. If this is correct, is there a way to understand which one is?

Comment: @Numb3rs That is correct. Unfortunately, we can't know which one it is as that would require that we know whether the function $f$ is the zero function or not. If the function $f$ is the zero function, then the dimension is $0$, if it is not, then the dimension is $1$.

Comment: Thank you so much for having made me understand. Just the last question, a curiosity: was my initial interpretation correct? Assuming it's not the zero function. I mean $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ I though something like $f(x, y, z) = (xy+z, x^y-z^2)$ so as you see, three dimensions in input and a $2$ dimensional vector in output. Yet, I am having difficulties in picturing an example of such a function whose range has dimension $1$. So perhaps my interpretation is wrong. Is there some example to clarify this?

Comment: @Numb3rs There are many functions you can define such that the dimension of their range is $1$. Think about all the lines in $R^2$. But I guess that would warrant an entirely new question in itself!

Comment: Thank you so much. I will ask then a separate question!