# Can someone please provide an example of such a function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

So, related to this question: [What is the dimension of this function? (And mostly: what does this mean?)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4580610/what-is-the-dimension-of-this-function-and-mostly-what-does-this-mean)

After having understood in a real good way (thanks @seeker) what it meant, I was asking for a possible example. Here I write again the function:

$$f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2 \qquad \qquad f(\mathbb{R}^3)\subseteq \text{span} (0, 1)$$

Here I am asking only for an eample of such a function, provided that the dimensions of $f(\mathbb{R}^3)$ are either zero or $1$.

I am asking for some example when the dimension is $1$.

Comment: $f(x,y,z)=(0,1)$ for all $x,y,z$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Ah. It was "just" that? o.o Wow.

Comment: $f(x,y,z)=(xyz,0)$ and many others such that always the image of $(x,y,z)$ be a vector of axe of $Y$ i,e. a vector of the form $\lambda e_2$ where $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is the canonical base of $\mathbb R^2$